# Function composition with lists

Tags: haskell

I want to create a function that receive three lists: the first is a list of binary functions, the second and the third are lists of unary functions.
The results must be like this:

```
 \x y -> f (g x) (h y)
```

This is a test I have done...

```
composeF xa xb xc = [a . (b c) | a <- xa, b <- xb, c <- xc]
```

... but I don't know how to correctly compose those functions.

Comment: Do you want to generate a function for **every** combination, or more a `zip` style?

Comment: A function for every combination :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can simply **put a lambda expression in the head** of the list comprehension:

```
composeF fs gs hs = [ \x y -> f (g x) (h y) | f <- fs, g <- gs, h <- hs]
```

I also took the liberty to rename the given lists to `fs`, `gs` and `hs` since these are usually names reserved for functions (but evidently there is nothing wrong with `as`, `bs` and `cs`, you only give the reader a hint about the type of objects you want to process). In that case `composeF` has type:

```
composeF :: [t1 -> t2 -> t] -> [t3 -> t1] -> [t4 -> t2] -> [t3 -> t4 -> t]
```

Which seems the requested type.

You can syntactically shorten your lambda expression a bit further into:

```
\x -> f (g x) . h
```

so:

```
composeF fs gs hs = [ \x -> f (g x) . h | f <- fs, g <- gs, h <- hs]
```

Note that you will construct a function for **every combination** so given `fs` has length 3, `gs` has length 5 and `hs` has length 8, the generated list will have 3 × 5 × 8 = 120 elements.

Comment: Thanks, explained very well.

Comment: I would call that a shortening, not an optimization. It is no faster (of course), and the version with `\x y -> ...` is very clearly a function that wants two arguments, so I would call it more optimal in the only way that matters here: legibility.

Comment: @amalloy: changed it to *syntactically shorten*, better?

Comment: If you must. I'd rather just not suggest the shorter, less readable version at all. Why stop where you have, instead of recommending `(. h) . f . g`?

Comment: @amalloy: because based on the question, I don't think this is currently the level of Haskell we should introduce; each answer should try to push the user one level higher, not 3 :)